# Xelement is not a valid windows runtime type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, .net-4.5

I am porting a windows phone 7 app to windows run time. In my wp7 app I have:

```
public sealed class Packet
{
  public XElement _element;

  public Packet(XElement element)
  {


  }
}
```

It says XElement is not recognized as a valid Windows run time type.

Please can anybody explain why is so.

Comment: Did you include these ? `using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Is this an app or a library? If it's an app, why is the class `public`?

Comment: Also, having public fields is considered a bad practice in .Net. You should use properties instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types exposed by Windows Runtime Components must be Windows Runtime types ...

*Externally, the members of your types can expose only Windows Runtime types for their parameters and return values.*

... from [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).